# Lookup Control Breaks after Search

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lookup, lightning-recordeditform

Seems there is a bug in the lightning lookup control. After using the search for more results:
[image]

and clicking on a value. The lookup stops responding and it is no longer possible to select any values. I've traced this to here:

[image]

Seems that something in the search modal sets the internalValue to an array with one item 'null'. And then the handle select just gives up.

Comment: Could you provide some additional info and code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tracked it down. It was only happening on lookups to Product2, and was a result of the ExternalId (standard field) being populated. I didn't dig in fully, but noticed that when selecting a product from the search page, the handleInput method was sending around the externalId instead of the salesforce ID. Somewhere in the code it ends up going to [null], but I stopped short of tracking it down.

tldr; Clearing the ExternalId field on our products allows to the look up to function correctly